# How to properly exit a multi-threaded and multi-processes program?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, semaphore

I have to code a C program that runs several processes.
If one of these processes stops, I need them all other processes to exit properly (free everything + close every opened semaphores).
Processes can stop either because an error occured or because they died (a specific condition related to my program's purpose).
I only can use semaphores (no mutexes) and the pthread_create, pthread_join, ptthread_detach functions, no signals allowed !

What I did: I run 3 threads per process:
1 thread to execute the main purpose of my process (M),
1 thread to check for any other process' death (D),
1 thread to check for any other process' error (E),

Thread M just runs by default.
For threads D and E, I have a semaphore named /death (or /error) that is worth 0 when initialized. Whenever a process dies (or encounters an error), it posts this semaphore so it will enter in the respective thread, free everything, then posts it again to allow any other process to free again and quit and etc...
Here is an example for the death thread:

```
void *D_thread(void *args)
{
   sem_wait(death_sem);
   frees_everything();
   sem_post(death_sem);
   exit(0);
}
```

I have 2 issues:

1. While entering the D thread for example, my process will start freeing all its resources, while its M thread is still running and trying to access to these resources. Could this be a source of errors and should I then protect this with another semaphore ?
2. My processes will free one after the other, resulting potentially in a slow exit if many processes run together.

Do you think this is a good method or can you think of something else more efficient ? Again: I only can use semaphores (no mutexes) and the pthread_create, pthread_join, pthread_detach functions, no signals allowed !

Comment: What language? And why are you limited to semaphores?

Comment: Threads or processes?  Your title says threads, but your question states processes.

Comment: I code in C and my program runs several processes that each run 3 threads. I edited my post for clarification.
I am limited to semaphores because it is an assignment for school.
All the students I know that did this project had leaks when exiting the program but I do not want leaks so I need to be careful and wisely create semaphores that will permit me to exit in a nice way